# Reading a html page and inserting it to database using classic asp

Tags: html, database, file-io, replace, asp-classic

I am trying to read a html page (file) including its tags line by line, and then inserting it to database using classic ASP. My problem is that I can not read html tags Like

```
    <p>Test</p>
```

or

```
    <td width="20%">Hello</td>
```

instead I read "Test" or "Hello".
I also know that I have to convert " to ', when am I supposed to replace it?
Here is my read code:

```
        Dim url,strArr,xmlhttp,lineno
        url = "http://localhost/0/questions/q.html"
        set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")            
        xmlhttp.open "GET", url, false
        xmlhttp.send ""
        strArr = split(xmlhttp.responseText,vbcrlf)
        set xmlhttp = nothing
        for lineno=0 to ubound(strArr)
           ' Here I do replacement, parsing and then insertion to database
        next
```

Comment: Your code is working as is and I do not know what are you asking. Most likely you making mistake somewhere else. I just got  HTML source for this specific page and write it into database using your code and my DB connection without any problem. Show code where exactly you make and then see that response.write hello.

Comment: we are here for fun but would be nice if you mark what help you as an answer, not just up-vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Dim url,strArr,xmlhttp,lineno
    url = "http://localhost/0/questions/q.html"
    set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")            
    xmlhttp.open "GET", url, false
    xmlhttp.send ""
    strArr = split(xmlhttp.responseText,vbcrlf)
    set xmlhttp = nothing
    for lineno=0 to ubound(strArr)
      response.write(Replace(strArr(lineno),"<","<'"))
    next
```

If you placed just response.write(strArr(lineno)) in your page you will see only what is inside html tag not the tag itself. But if you do insert of that strArr(lineno) into database all will be there.For as long as you replace all apostrophes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use responseHTML instead of responseText:

```
strArr = split(xmlhttp.responseHTML,vbcrlf)
```